# Is unknown certainty oxymoronic?

Tags: figures-of-speech, oxymoron

If someone started a story thus,

> In a time lost, in a certain yet unknown place, is the Castle of Umberdeen ...

How could an entity be a certainty and yet unknown? It does not make sense. But then, do we need to apply logical mathematical principles to a fantasy romance.

Is the kick-off sentence to the story oxymoronic? Perhaps, someone has a different interpretation of "certain".

Comment: certain means: specific but not explicitly named or stated. https://www.google.com/search?q=certain+definition

Comment: Indeed, the castle sits in a certain place, irrespective of whether or not we know where that place is.

Comment: If there is a castle somewhere it certainly has a place, even if the place is unknown to the author and readers. But a castle in a certain unknown place is not optimal as "certain" is superfluous. I would formulate it differently: in a place that is yet unknown to us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of *certain* in this context actually means *particular*, so if you imagine the sentence as *...in a particular yet unknown*, it's not so confusing. Although the use of *certain* in this way is common and it's fine, it's not oxymoronic because the nuance of meaning is different from what you were thinking.

Answer (score 3):

It is not an oxymoron.  Unknown is something that you do not know here - the castle.  I would need to see more of the text but it sounds like the author is describing something that has not been visited.

On the certain side, well they know there is a castle there.  They either have seen it or heard about it or whatever.  So the statements are not opposites because they are (most likely) describing different aspects of the castle.

Comment: And remember that an oxymoron is _an apparent contradiction in terms that has a sensible interpretation if one is prepared to accept unusual shades of meaning_ , not a contradiction in terms. Although arty types feel licensed to push the boundaries. Perhaps some should be locked up in Umberdeen Castle.

Answer (score -1):

At face value, the phrase taken by itself, 'the certainty of the unknown' can describe:
1) that there will certainly always be an unknown; or
2) that within the unknown there exists or is caused to exist something of certainty; or
3) that the existence of the unknown gives rise within human emotion and understanding, to a need for certainty.

There are probably other interpretations as well.
(1) is universally accepted as fact.
(2) is speculation.
(3) is accepted as probable.

“Unknown certainty” is simpler, and is something else again.
Its meaning could be as in this sentence: ‘There are as-yet-unknown certainties.”  In other words, there are facts that we are still unaware of.
It's akin to #1, but slightly different.

These are my suggestions.

Comment: Hi Myrrh, welcome to English Language & Usage. It looks like you've responded to the question *title*, which unfortunately misrepresents the problem expressed in the body of the question. You can always delete your post if you'd prefer to tackle another question rather than retrofitting your answer to this one. If you think you might use our site again (and I hope you do!), please make sure you take the **site [Tour]**. :-)